# How is it possible to Fragment.getActivity() returns null in Fragment.onPrepareOptionsMenu()?

Tags: android, android-fragments

How is it possible to `Fragment.getActivity()` returns null in `Fragment.onPrepareOptionsMenu()`?

I have found rare bug sent by users.

```
@Override
void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // ...
    getActivity(); // <-- is Null
    // ...
}
```

If a `Fragment` is detached from an activity how can it participate in forming activity's actionbar content?

Comment: are you certain on `detached()` was called? or is it because `getActivity()` is null? do you use `getActivity()` else where in your code? does that return null? did you override `onAttach(Activity act)`?

Comment: I guess your fragment is not attached to a Activity at the moment.

Comment: keep activity reference when onAttach is called.

Comment: @Elltz it's all about `getActivity()` returns null. Statement about detach is just my assumption. No, i'm not certain that `onDetached()` was called. I'm just trying to figure out how can it be that two conditions are true at the same time. `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` is called and `getActivity()` returns null? Yes `getActivity()` is used in different methods. No, it doesn't. No, i'don't override it.

Comment: @DERPA_CHIEF it could help as a simple check for null. But it doesn't give answer why is that possible?

Comment: @JoshuaByer i think so. But why then it's `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` gets called by the system?

Comment: for sake of facts please a copy of that error,since more information might be there

Comment: Same happens to me... IllegalStateException: Fragment is not attached to Actvity when I try calling getResources() from onPrepareOptionsMenu()... haven't found an answer yet :(